# Doesn't work the same code from the book <"Programming Objective-c 4th edition" Stephen Kochan>

Tags: objective-c, c

Why it says that **numerator and denominator** in the category **MathOps** is undeclared variable ?

It is in the **Chapter 11** and the **Program 11.1**

Can't understand why it doesn't work, because it is the same code as in the book without any mistakes.

Please help

Code:

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>  
#import "complex.h"  
#import "Fraction.h"  
#import "XYPoint.h"  

@interface Fraction (MathOps)  
-(Fraction *)add:(Fraction *) f;  
-(Fraction *)mul:(Fraction *) f;  
-(Fraction *)sub:(Fraction *) f;  
-(Fraction *)div:(Fraction *) f;  

@end  

@implementation Fraction (MathOps)  
-(Fraction *)add:(Fraction *) f  
{  
    Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc]init];  

    result.numerator = (numerator * f.denominator)+(denominator * f.numerator);   

// numerator and denominator: Using undeclared variables.  

    result.denominator = denominator * f.denominator;  
}  
-(Fraction *)mul:(Fraction *) f  
{  
    Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc]init];  
    result.numerator = numerator * f.numerator;  
    result.denominator = denominator * f.denominator;  

    // numerator and denominator: Using undeclared variables.  
}  
-(Fraction *)sub:(Fraction *) f {}  
-(Fraction *)div:(Fraction *) f {}  
@end  

typedef Fraction *FractionObj;  
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])  
{  

    @autoreleasepool {  
        complex *imaginary= [[complex alloc]init];  
        complex *real = [[complex alloc]init];  
        complex *results;  

        [real setReal:1];  
        [real setImaginary:2];  
        [real print];  

        [imaginary setReal:2];  
        [imaginary setImaginary:1];  
        [imaginary print];  

        results = [real add: imaginary];  
        [results print];  
        NSLog(@"FRACTIONS!");  
        Fraction *a = [[Fraction alloc]init];  
        Fraction *b = [[Fraction alloc]init];  
        id resultFraction;  

        [a setTo:20 over:3];  
        [b setTo:1 over:3];  
        [b minusSign];  
        [a minusSign];  

        id ab = a;  
        id ba = b;  
        [ab print: 0];  
        NSLog(@"-");  
        [ba print: 0];  
        NSLog(@"=");  
        resultFraction = [ab multiplyN: ba];  
        [resultFraction print: 1];  

      XYPoint *xy = [[XYPoint alloc]init];  

        [xy setX:100 andY:110];  
        [xy print];  

        NSLog(@"VERIFYING \n \n \n");  
        Fraction *fraction = [[Fraction alloc]init];  
        complex *Complex = [[complex alloc]init];  
        id number = [[complex alloc]init];  

        if([fraction isMemberOfClass: [complex class]])  
            NSLog(@"Fraction is member of class complex");  
        if([Complex isMemberOfClass: [NSObject class]])  
            NSLog(@"complex is member of class NSObject");  
        if([Complex isKindOfClass: [NSObject class]])  
            NSLog(@"complex is kind of class NSObject");  
        if([fraction isKindOfClass: [Fraction class]])  
            NSLog(@"Fraction is kind of class Fraction");  
        if([fraction respondsToSelector: @selector(print)])  
           NSLog(@"Fraction respond to selector print");  
        if([Complex respondsToSelector: @selector(print)])  
           NSLog(@"Complex responds to print");  
        if([Fraction instancesRespondToSelector: @selector(print)])  
           NSLog(@"Fraction's instances respond to print");  
        if([number respondsToSelector: @selector (print)])  
           NSLog(@"number responds to print");  
        if([number isKindOfClass: [complex class]])  
           NSLog(@"number is kind of class complex");  
        if([[number class] respondsToSelector:@selector (alloc)])  
           NSLog(@"Number class responds to alloc");  

        if([a counter]!=1){ NSLog(@"%i times was invoked method multiplyN", a.counter); }  
        else { NSLog(@"Only %i time was invoked method multiplyN", a.counter);}  

        typedef enum {Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday} Day;  

    }  

    return 0;  
}
```

**Fraction.h**:

```
    @interface Fraction : NSObject
@property int numerator, denominator, counter;

//methods
@end
```

**Fraction.m**

```
@implementation
@synthesize numerator, denominator, counter;

//methods

@end
```

Comment: Yes:    "Use of undeclared identifier 'numerator'; did you mean 'NSEnumerator'? "

Comment: Can you please show us where are you declaring *numerator* and *denominator*? Also I think janusfidel means the exact error message (copy-paste).

Comment: This is more of a guess than an answer but, if you defined numerator and denominator as properties of `Fraction`, you need `self.` in front of them in your references.

Comment: I wrote the code where I declared numerator and denominator.  **Phillip Mills** where to write self ?

Comment: Where you reference them, such as `result.denominator = self.denominator * f.denominator;`.  (Read some documentation about how `property` and `synthesize` work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `self.` prefix to your code:

```
result.numerator = (self.numerator * f.denominator)+(self.denominator * f.numerator);
```

Answer (score 1):

you might want to check your Fraction class file .h, check if you have a set property of numerator and denominator  there.

```
@property(nonatomic, ...) Type *numerator
@property(nonatomic, ...) Type *denominator
```

and also in your .m file, there should be

```
@synthesize numerator, denominator
```

or , in your xcode, point your mouse to that numerator or denominator while holding  Command key then click the variable, xcode will take you to the file where the variable is declared, if its not declared, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using numerator and denominator without any previous setup of the variables. You may be confused by the fact that these variables have the same names as other variables, but if they aren't associated with the file they're being called from then your program won't recognize them. Your synthesize statement probably needs to be moved to underneath your @implementation statement. I'm somewhat confused by the fact that the code you're showing contains no declaration of numerator and denominator, and I'm sure that your compiler is too.